# Can I push bundle to repository?

Tags: git

I have a bundle file and I want to push it to a remote repository.
I searched in the web but didn't find any answer that help.

Can you help me with that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "a bundle file" (a zip/tar)? Do you mean registry not repository (like npm)?

Comment: repo.bundle, is a file that contain all branch of a repository

Comment: @evolutionxbox - surely by "a bundle file" they mean a bundle file.  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger ignorance is a common failing I deal with.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Ah, but ignorance is easily cured. Unless you have apathy too, as in the old joke: Q: What's the difference between ignorance and apathy? A: I don't know and I don't care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to directly push a bundle.  Why not just fetch the bundle into a local clone and push from there?